# find norm of linear operator

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

let $\mathbf{C}[0,1]$ be the space of continuous real-valued functions on $[0,1]$ with sup norm and $\mathbf{T}: \mathbf{C}[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be  linear operator such that :

> $\mathbf{T}(\mathbf{f})=\int_{0}^{1} \mathbf{f}(\sqrt{\mathbf{x}}) \mathrm{d} \mathbf{x} \quad,(\mathbf{f} \in \mathbf{C} [0,1])$

now find $\|\mathrm{T}\|$ ?

\begin{array}{l}
1){\|\mathrm{T}\|=\infty} \\
2){\|\mathrm{T}\|=\mathrm{2}} \\
3){\|\mathrm{T}\|=\frac{1}{\mathrm{2}}} \\
4){\|\mathrm{T}\|=1}
\end{array}

we know $$\|T\|=\sup\{\|Tx\|:x\in X,\|x\|\le1\}=\{\frac{\|Tx\|}{\|x\|}:x\in X, x\neq0\}$$ and $\|f(x)\| =\sup_{x\in [0,1]}|f(x)|=\max_{x\in [0,1]}|f(x)|$ for $f(x)=1 $ we have $\|T(f(x))\| =1 $ so option $3$ is false

Answer (score 2):

You have $|Tf| \le \int_0^1 \|f\| dx = \|f\|$, so $\|T\| \le 1$.
 Let $f(x) = 1$ for all $x$ to get $|Tf| = 1$ hence $\|T\| =1 $.

Answer (score 1):

What you did show that the norm of $T$ is bigger or equal to one. Using $\lvert f\left(\sqrt x\right)\rvert\leqslant \lVert f\rVert_\infty$ for all $x$, we can deduce that the norm of $T$ is smaller or equal to one.

Answer (score 0):

Call $t=\sqrt{x}$. Then your Intégral becomes
$$
I=2\int_0^1 tf(t)dt
$$
For $f$ with $|f|\le 1$ you have
$$
|I|\le 2\int_0^1 tdt\le 1
$$
Hence the norm is 1.